# Excel - copy row data from other sheet if first column match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

So I will have a data table in sheet1 which some rows data are missing and I will have a list of those missed data in sheet2.

I wanna check "name" of each rows of sheet1 and if it match the "name" row of sheet2 then copy the next 3 cells from sheet2 into sheet1.

[sheet1 data are missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OciFu.png)

[sheet2 data that wanna copy to sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whf24.png)

Note that : my real data is about 9,000 rows and the missing data is just about 300 rows. I don't want to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a Vlookup? You can create a separate column, and use a vlookup formula there, and just drag it down.

Answer (score 0):

You can put these formulas in column b,c&d respectively. Just that you would need to replace A1 with the cell address for the name you want to look up. And this would only work if the names were unique. IF theres some other part of your sheet that has unique identifiers for all 9000 rows then you could use that as your match case instead

`=Index(Sheet2!B:B;Match(A1;Sheet2!A:A;0))
 =Index(Sheet2!C:C;Match(A1;Sheet2!A:A;0))
 =Index(Sheet2!D:D;Match(A1;Sheet2!A:A;0))`